# C# ActiveX error during creation

Tags: c#, activex

I've faced with following problem:

I have an ActiveX Control , on dev machine it is working as expected , 
when trying to create it on other machine I am getting the following error

```
Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am using following line to create it:

```
 var activeX = new ActiveXObject("ScannerViewerControl.ScannerViewer");
```

I've used installshield for deployment , and marked .NET Com Interop.

I am able to find in registry path to the .dll under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.

What am I missing ???

Comment: Use SysInternals' ProcMon utility.  You'll see the program searching for the file and not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing a dependency for the active-x DLL on the client machine.  Depending on what version of VS you have installed, you might have a tool called depends, which you can point at a DLL and see the dependencies that are required.

Comment: Have you tried creating a vbscript that creates the object?  That will let you know if it is a problem with the COM object or something with how you are using it.

Comment: Did you write the COM object or is it supplied by a vendor?  If you wrote it, did you write it in .net or is it a C++/VB6 COM object?

Comment: It it C# ActiveX Control , so it's .NET Com.

Comment: From the other posts i can understand that assemble wasn't registered... tha seems very wierd for me since I am using regasm.exe /codebase /mydll.dll then I am adding to GAC by Gacutil.exe /i mydll.dll , what can be wrong there ?